# Novels set in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, novel, suggested-order, marvel-cinematic-universe

I've recently started reading some of the Star Wars extended universe novels, and have really started to enjoy them.  I'm also a big fan of the Marvel Cinematic Universe and the storylines and characters in the films.  Are there any novels set in this universe?  If so, where could I get a list?  What order should they be read in (including the timing of watching the films)?

Comment: Just to clarify lists of works are considered to be off topic.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Hmm. Asking whether something exists isn't the same as asking for a complete list.

Comment: @Richard He does ask where he can get a list and for recommendations which are both off topic to ask for.  The only thing he can ask if there are novels set in the universe.

Comment: There are a couple of [junior novelisations](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3366824-iron-man) which recap events of the film, but I’m fairly sure there aren’t any novels with their own plotlines.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 But suggested reading order questions are on topic.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cinematic

Comment: Anyway that I can improve [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117643/55866)?

Answer (score 6):

There a number of tie in comic books, listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_tie-in_comics#Publication_info), that are collected in various trade paperbacks:

- Iron Man: I Am Iron Man
- Captain America: First Vengeance
- Road to Marvel's The Avengers
- The Avengers Prelude: Fury's Big Week
- The Avengers Prelude: Black Widow Strikes
- The Avengers Initiative
- Iron Man 3 Prelude
- Thor: The Dark World Prelude
- Captain America: The Winter Soldier Prelude

Comment: I want to say theres no tie in novels, but I haven't been able to prove that to myself

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Th novel *Black Widow: Forever Red* by Margaret Stohl is set in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

This was confirmed by the author via twitter:

> **I was wondering what reality Forever Red takes place in? Is it Earth-616, Earth-199999 (Cinematic Universe), or somewhere all new?**
>
> basically MTU which is how I think of the Marvel TV universe - cinematic but still with Coulson very much around!
>
> [source](https://twitter.com/mstohl/status/671719567941435393)

It's possible that the upcoming novel, *Daredevil: The Man Without Fear* by Paul Crilley will also be set in the MCU, but I don't think it's been confirmed.

Comment: see also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115622/is-the-book-black-widow-forever-red-part-of-the-marvel-cinematic-universe

Answer (score 2):

There are novelizations out there- meaning mass market paperback which are pretty much the script of the movie expanded into a novel. Often they're off due to being likely based on early versions of the script, stuff adlibed while shooting and such. I'm a huge fan of novelizations as I've encountered some REALLY good ones (specifically *Batman Begins* and *The Chronicles of Riddick*)

For Marvel Cinematic Universe I know that there are novelizations of the *Iron Man* movies. I've read 1 & 2 and remember them being okay. [Here's the first one on Amazon.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034550609X)

From an investigation on Amazon it seems that there are only "Junior Novelization" books for the other movies, meaning they're designed for kids and thus may not be all that enjoyable.

Answer (score 2):

- Black Widow: *Forever Red* also has a sequel, *Red Vengance*.
- I know that all of the movies up until the Avengers have a junior novelization
- I am pretty sure that Iron Man: *Gauntlet* is set in the MCU, but I am not certain.